# tinyos implementation of routing table for multiple nodes

Tags: c, tinyos, nesc, radio-transmission

I am writing a module implementation in nesC for a network of 7 motes identified by the means of ID. Each mote is assumed to have a routing table with a specific structure, defined as:

```
      // Define routing table structure
 
    typedef nx_struct routing_table_t {

        nx_uint16_t destination;
        nx_uint16_t next_hop;
        nx_uint16_t cost;
        } routing_table_t;
    
    routing_table_t routing_table[7]; // 7 since I assume to have 7 nodes in the network
```

I have launched a TOSSIM simulation of my project but I keep getting this type of errors on my .nc file:

```
RadioRouteC.nc: In function `Receive.receive':
RadioRouteC.nc:208: invalid type argument of `unary *'
RadioRouteC.nc:238: invalid type argument of `unary *'
RadioRouteC.nc:240: invalid type argument of `unary *'
RadioRouteC.nc:241: invalid type argument of `unary *'
RadioRouteC.nc:242: invalid type argument of `unary *'
RadioRouteC.nc:264: invalid type argument of `unary *'
```

The problem seems to hide in the definition of the routing table structure. The function Receive.receive that I am trying to debug looks as following:

```
event message_t* Receive.receive(message_t* bufPtr, 
                   void* payload, uint8_t len) {
    /*
    * THIS EVENT IMPLEMENTS FOLLOWING FUNCTIONALITIES:
    * Parse the receive packet.
    * Perform the packet send using the generate_send function 
    * Implement the LED logic and print LED status on Debug
    */

    
    // Update LED status
    int code = 10310011; // take my person code
    digit = code % 10; // take the digit
    led_index = digit % 3; // perform the modulo division if the digit
        if (led_index == 0) { // if index equals 0, toggle only LED 0 (same for 1 and 2 accordingly)
            call Leds.led0Toggle();
        } else if (led_index == 1) {
            call Leds.led1Toggle();
        } else if (led_index == 2) {
            call Leds.led2Toggle();
        }
    dbg("LED", "LED%d is toggled.\n", led_index); // notify about LED status change
    code = code / 10; // update the value of the person code (becomes 1 digit shorter for the next msg receipt)
    
  
// Parse the received packet
    switch (bufPtr->type) 
    { // implement the fuctionality switch based on message type that can be 0,1 or 2
        case 0: // Data message
            // Check if the node is the destination
            if (bufPtr->destination == TOS_NODE_ID) {
                // If the node is the destination, print the received data
                dbg("Data", "Received data %d from %d\n", bufPtr->value, bufPtr->sender);
            } else {
                // If the node is not the destination, forward the data - to do so, check the routing table
                // Check if the node has an entry in the routing table
                if (routing_table[bufPtr->destination].destination != 0) {
                    // If the node has an entry in the routing table, forward the data
                    bufPtr->sender = TOS_NODE_ID;
                    generate_send(routing_table[bufPtr->destination]->next_hop, bufPtr, 0); // ERROR LINE 208
                }
            }
            break;
        case 1: // Route Request message
            // Check if the node is the requested node
            if (bufPtr->node_requested == TOS_NODE_ID) {
                // If the node is the requested node, send a Route Reply message
                message_t reply;
                reply.type = 2;
                reply.sender = TOS_NODE_ID;
                reply.node_requested = bufPtr->node_requested;
                reply.cost = 1;
                generate_send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &reply, 2);
            } else {
                // If the node is not the requested node, broadcast the Route Request message
                // Check if the node has already sent a Route Request message
                if (route_req_sent == FALSE) {
                    // If the node has not sent a Route Request message, broadcast the Route Request message
                    generate_send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, bufPtr, bufPtr->type);
                    route_req_sent = TRUE;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2: // Route Reply message
            // Check if the node is the requested node
            if (bufPtr->node_requested == TOS_NODE_ID) {
                // If the node is the requested node, do nothing
            } else {
                // If the node is not the requested node, check if the node has an entry in the routing table
                if (routing_table[bufPtr->node_requested].destination == 0 || routing_table[bufPtr->node_requested]->cost > bufPtr->cost) // ERROR LINE 238
{
                    // If the node does not have an entry in the routing table or the new cost is lower than the current cost, update the routing table
                    routing_table[bufPtr->node_requested]->destination = bufPtr->node_requested; // ERROR LINE 240
                    routing_table[bufPtr->node_requested]->next_hop = bufPtr->sender; // ERROR LINE 241
                    routing_table[bufPtr->node_requested]->cost = bufPtr->cost + 1; // ERROR LINE 242
                    // Forward the Route Reply message
                    bufPtr->cost += 1;
                    generate_send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, bufPtr, bufPtr->type);
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            // Handle any unexpected message types
            break;
        }
    
    // Check if the node is node 1
    if (TOS_NODE_ID == 1) {
        // If the node is node 1, check if the node has an entry in the routing table
            if (routing_table[1].destination == 7) { // checks if node 1 has an entry for node 7
                // If the node has an entry in the routing table, send a Data message
                message_t data;
                data.type = 0; // message type = data message
                data.sender = TOS_NODE_ID; // data sender is the current node (1)
                data.destination = 7; // message is destined to node 7
                data.value = 5; // message value is 5
                generate_send(routing_table[7]->next_hop, &data, 0); // ERROR LINE 264
            }
                 else {
                 // If the node does not have an entry in the routing table, send a Route Request message
                message_t req;
                req.type = 1;
                req.node_requested = 7;
                generate_send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &req, 1);
            }

        
    return bufPtr;}

    }
```

Any ideas on how to modify this function to make it work?

To provide you some context on what I expect the .Receive function to do:

1. When the Timer1.fired() event is triggered, the code sets the packet type to 1 and sets the node requested to 7, then sends the packet to the broadcast address.

```
  event void Timer1.fired() {
    /*
    * Implement here the logic to trigger the Node 1 to send the first REQ packet
    */
    message_t packet;
    packet.type = 1;
    packet.node_requested = 7;
    generate_send(TOS_BCAST_ADDR, &packet, 1); // 1 for route req message
  }
```

2. When the Receive.receive() event is triggered, the code parses the received packet.

a.   If the packet type is 0 (data message), the code checks if the node is the destination.

If it is, it prints the received data.

 If it is not, it checks the routing table to see if it has an entry for the destination node, and if it does, it forwards the data.

b.  If the packet type is 1 (route request message), the code checks if the node is the requested node.

If it is, it sends a route reply message.

If it is not, it checks if it has already sent a route request message, and if it has not, it broadcasts the route request message.

c.   If the packet type is 2 (route reply message), the code checks if the node is the requested node.

If it is not, it checks if it has an entry in the routing table, and

 if it does not or the new cost is lower than the current cost, it updates the routing table and forwards the route reply message.

d.  Finally, if the node is node 1, it checks if 5 seconds have passed since the radio is on, and if it has, it checks if it has an entry in the routing table.

If it does not, it sends a route request message, and if it does, it sends a data message.

The data message variable is defined as follows:

```
// Define message structure
  typedef nx_struct message_t {
    // Define mesage type
    nx_uint8_t type; // 0 for data msg, 1 for for route request, 2 for route reply
    
    // Data messages
    nx_uint16_t destination;
    nx_uint16_t value;


    // Route Reply messages
    nx_uint16_t sender;
    nx_uint16_t node_requested; // Route Request msg
    nx_uint16_t cost;
} message_t;
```

**Disclaimer: I am a total beginner to nesC, so the function might have problems in addition to the one mentioned above.**
Would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `routing_table_t routing_table[TOS_NODE_ID];` looks weird to me.. shouldn't that be something like `routing_table_t routing_table[NUMBER_OF_NODES];`?

Comment: that's a runtime error? Can you indicate which line it's happening on?

Comment: yes, it is a runtime error, gonna modify initial post to highlight the lines on which it is happening. I think, it has sth to deal with how I reference the variable routing table

Comment: provided additional details on the function